# Azure Cloud Service Logging and viewing whats happening

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-monitoring

I have an azure cloud service and I am struggling and feel I have exhausted all avenues on trying to identify what is going wrong. When I try hit one of the actions I get an internal server 500 however I can't see no stack trace of this at all!

I have enabled diagnostics via the setting:

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

And within azure portal I have setup the connection string which I am monitoring via Azure Management Studio. However, for the life of me I cannot see whats going wrong.

I have remoted onto the box to and tried it locally and nothing is seen in the event log, no exception.

What I have done, is change the setting via portal to another value and back to the original and for some reason that seems to make the app work. However, this workaround is unacceptable and for future reference I would like to see the error it is throwing.

Cheers, DS.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with Cloud Services, I'd advice you to set up a [free NewRelic account](http://newrelic.com/azure), [add the NewRelic package to your Cloud Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-new-relic-cloud-services-dotnet-application-performance-management/), and check NewRelic's findings.

It's extremely helpful and it will dig up and tell you exactly in which part of your code is the error and the stack trace.

Debugging Apps in the Cloud without something like NewRelic or AppInsights feels almost like shooting in the dark.